# Where is virtualenv's deactivate defined?

Tags: terminal, shell, alias, bash-alias

Virtualenv defines an alias for the command `deactivate` as seen in `yourvirtualenv/bin/activate.csh`. What I'm curious about is where `deactivate` resides, because when I issue an `alias` command `deactivate` does not appear in the list of active aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're actually running `bash` rather than `csh`, the script you want to look at is `yourvirtualenv/bin/activate` (not `yourvirtualenv/bin/activate.csh`), which defines a *function* called `deactivate`, not an *alias*. You can see this with the `type` command:

```
$ type deactivate
deactivate is a function
deactivate () 
{ 
    typeset env_postdeactivate_hook;
    typeset old_env;
    virtualenvwrapper_run_hook "pre_deactivate";
    env_postdeactivate_hook="$VIRTUAL_ENV/$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR/postdeactivate";
    old_env=$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV");
    virtualenv_deactivate $1;
    virtualenvwrapper_run_hook "post_deactivate" "$old_env";
    if [ ! "$1" = "nondestructive" ]; then
        unset -f virtualenv_deactivate > /dev/null 2>&1;
        unset -f deactivate > /dev/null 2>&1;
    fi
}
```

Comment: I saw the function definition as well, but did not know how it related to the alias in the .csh file. Thanks a lot! Had no idea that you could define functions in this manner, as well as `type` out their definitions.